# How to perform Union using Linq as i performed in Mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-entities, union

This is How i performed Union between two different table with Different Column name , 
*I'm picking only date and amount from second table and pass null to rest of the columns *

```
  string query="select `Date`,`ItemName`,`ReqQty`, `Amount`,`TotalAmount` from ((SELECT s.`Date` ,i.`ItemName`, s.`ReqQty`,s.`Amount`,s.`TotalAmount` FROM `sale` as s join items as i on s.itemid=i.id where s.`partyId`='" + ddllist.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ) Union all ((select p.date,'','','Recieved', p.`amount` as Totalamount from `OrderPayment` as p where p.`partyId`='" + ddllist.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ))) tb order by `Date`";
```

but in linq i cant create false column like mysql as i passed null to column that i don't have .. it gives error, Here is my linq try

```
       var query1 = (from s in lam.sales where s.PartyId == 1 select new { Date = s.Date, Itemid = s.ItemId, Qty = s.ReqQty, Amount = s.Amount, TotalAmount = s.TotalAmount });

        var query2 = (from q in lam.paydetails where q.partyId == 1 select new { Date =(DateTime?) q.Date, Itemid = 0, Qty = (int?)null, Amount = (int?)null, TotalAmount = q.amount });
        var queryresult = query1.Concat(query2);
```

Sales Class

```
public partial class sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PartyId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReqQty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AvaibleQty { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Amount { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual item item { get; set; }
    public virtual partydetail partydetail { get; set; }
}
```

OrderPayment Class

```
public partial class orderpayment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> partyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public virtual partydetail partydetail { get; set; }
}
```

ItemClass Which is refencing to itemId in Sales Class

```
public partial class item
{
    public item()
    {
        this.sales = new HashSet<sale>();
        this.ordereds = new HashSet<ordered>();
        this.stocks = new HashSet<stock>();
        this.productions = new HashSet<production>();
        this.productions1 = new HashSet<production>();
        this.finishes = new HashSet<finish>();
        this.productions11 = new HashSet<production>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> minqty { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<sale> sales { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to mention:

(1) SQL union rules are more relaxed than LINQ. In LINQ (and in general), two anonymous type are considered the same if all fields **name** and **type** match.

(2) The SQL to LINQ union operator mapping is as follows:

```
SQL         LINQ
=========   =======
UNION       Union
UNION ALL   Concat
```

Applying them to your case:

```
var query1 = (from s in lam.sales.AsEnumerable() where s.PartyId == 1
              select new { s.Date, s.item, s.ReqQty, s.Amount, s.TotalAmount });

var query2 = (from q in lam.paydetails where q.partyId == 1
              select new { q.Date, item = "", ReqQty = "", Amount = "", TotalAmount = q.amount });

var queryresult = query1.Concat(query2);
```

Note that the above ensures that field names match, but you need also to ensure that types match (since I don't have them, I can't do that). For instance, if `s.ReqQty` and/or `s.Amount` are numeric types, you have to replace the corresponding `""` with `null` for nullable types or `0` (zero) for non nullable types.

**UPDATE:** Based on your data model classes, here is the actual working query:

```
var query1 = (from s in db.sales where s.PartyId == 1
              select new { s.Date, s.item, s.ReqQty, s.Amount, TotalAmount = (decimal?)s.TotalAmount });

var query2 = (from q in db.paydetails where q.partyId == 1
              select new { q.Date, item = (item)null, ReqQty = (int?)null, Amount = (int?)null, TotalAmount = q.amount });

var queryresult = query1.Concat(query2);
```

Comment: var query1 = (from s in lam.sales.AsEnumerable() where s.PartyId == 1 select new { Date=s.Date, item=s.ItemId, Qty=s.ReqQty,Amount= s.Amount,TotalAmount= s.TotalAmount });

var query2 = (from q in lam.paydetails.AsEnumerable() where q.partyId == 1 select new {Date=q.Date, item = 0, Qty = 0, Amount = 0, TotalAmount=q.amount });

 var queryresult = query1.Concat(query2);

Comment: Still getting same error 

Error 4 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'

Comment: Here paydetail tabledon't have Qty = 0, Amount = 0, TotalAmount=0 column,

And sales table has reqqty,amount,totalamount nullable int and ItemId is Non nullable Int

Comment: Just check the types and use casts where needed to make them equal. Like `item = 0, ReqQty = (int?)null, Amount = (int?)null`. Btw you don't need `AsEnumerable()`, you'd better remove it so the whole single query is executed against database.

Comment: var query1 = (from s in lam.sales where s.PartyId == 1 select new { Date = s.Date, Itemid = s.ItemId, Qty = s.ReqQty, Amount = s.Amount, TotalAmount = s.TotalAmount }).ToList();

            var query2 = (from q in lam.paydetails where q.partyId == 1 select new { Date =(DateTime?) q.Date, Itemid = 0, Qty = (int?)null, Amount = (int?)null, TotalAmount = q.amount }).ToList();
            var queryresult = query1.Concat(query2);

Comment: Something like this. No need `ToList` either. Does it work?

Comment: Still Problem is same ,i type cast values to nullable int and removed AsEnumarable()

Comment: removed toList (); stil same 

CS1928: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Concat<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ok, can you update your question with Sales and PayDetails (or whatever they are called) classes? And I'll update the answer with working query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106569/discussion-between-akash-and-ivan-stoev).